# Bitbucket jenkin kubernetes CI/CD

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, kubernetes

Can anyone share Jenkin file or steps to create CI/CD for bitbucket private repository to jenkin.

Build docker images and upload to docker hub and deploy to kubernetes.

i have try downloading plugin for bit bukcet no help so far.

I have not much-used Jenkin pipeline i have used freestyle project not much experience on Jenkin help appreciated.

```
pipeline {

  environment {
    registry = "*******/test_case"
    registryCredential = 'dockerhub'
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
  steps {
    git 'https://harshmanvar@bitbucket.org/harshmanvar/configuring-ci-cd-on-kubernetes-with-jenkins.git'
  }
}

    stage('Docker Build') {
      steps {
        sh "docker build -t ****/test_case:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ."
      }
    }
    stage('Docker Push') {
      steps {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dockerhub', passwordVariable: 'dockerHubPassword', usernameVariable: 'dockerHubUser')]) {
          sh "docker login -u ${env.dockerHubUser} -p ${env.dockerHubPassword}"
          sh "docker push ******/test_case:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Docker Remove Image') {
      steps {
        sh "docker rmi ********/test_case:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
      }
    }
    stage('Apply Kubernetes Files') {
      steps {
          withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kubeconfig']) {
          sh 'cat deployment.yaml | sed "s/{{BUILD_NUMBER}}/$BUILD_NUMBER/g" | kubectl apply -f -'
          sh 'kubectl apply -f service.yaml'
        }
      }
  }
}
post {
    success {
      slackSend(message: "Pipeline is successfully completed.")
    }
    failure {
      slackSend(message: "Pipeline failed. Please check the logs.")
    }
}
}
```

in first step it's not cloing repo while my repo is open not private.

Thanks

Comment: Is that supposed to be `git clone https://harshmanvar@bitbucket.org/...` instead of just `git https://harshmanvar@bitbucket.org/...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether your git repository private or not, just setup your private access token in git developer setting and add it to the Jenkins credential. After that try this script `cloning Git` stage:

```
stage('Cloning Git') {   
  steps {
    git credentialsId:'Your_Credential_Id', 
    url:'https://harshmanvar@bitbucket.org/harshmanvar/configuring-ci-cd-on-kubernetes-with-jenkins.git', branch:'master'
   }}
```

I hope this will be helpful to you.!

Comment: thanks for writing answer. i will check and test it.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout to your commit which was pushed to bitbucket instead of cloning manually 
what i did was this you can read more about it in official docs related to checkout, 
here is my first step

```
  stage('checkout scm'){
            script {
                try {
                    def scmVars = checkout scm
                    echo "$scmVars"
                    bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'INPROGRESS', credentialsId: 'OAuth_Bit_Notify' )
                } catch(err) {
                    bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED',  buildDescription: 'unable to clone repo with submodule', credentialsId: 'OAuth_Bit_Notify' )
                }
            }
        }
```

bitbucketStatusNotify is a plugin used over here to send status to bitbucket,
hope it helps